# roboflow yoloV5 training same size problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, yolo, roboflow

i am trying to train model via roboflow yolov5 notebook on colab. i always use pre-labeled roboflow data. and the problem is : the all final pt weight files has the same size (14.6 mb).

the big data or tiny data, there is no difference among sizes. i think it's ridiculous. can someone explain it?

colab notebook :https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gDZ2xcTOgR39tGGs-EZ6i3RTs16wmzZQ

Comment: Are you sure you’re pulling the correct weights for the most recent run of the model? The first run is stored in the `exp` directory, then `exp2`, `exp3`, etc.

Comment: What do you mean big data or tiny data? The size of the training set?

Comment: even if the dataset's huge (for example it contains 5000 images) which you used during training, output weight file size is fixed (14.6 mb)

Comment: What makes you think that is incorrect? The saved file only depends on the number of weights and the binary format (floating point), it does not depend on the size of the training set.

Comment: but i have trained on other notebooks, they arent all time fixed. i am going to check again later.

Comment: when training was going on the pt file has 57 MB size, but when it has finished was being 14.13 MB . i think optimizer do it. now i wonder which is there any impact of detection quality of model. thank you.

Comment: Please post the relevant code *here*, *not* in external repos; see how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

The size of weights file is proportional to the number of parameters in the model which is defined by the architecture. It doesn't have anything to do with the size of the dataset or the number of epochs/amount of time trained.

The only thing that will affect the filesize of the weights is what version of the model you use. YOLOv5 comes in several sizes:

[image: YOLOv5 model sizes]

> when training was going on the pt file has 57 MB size, but when it has finished was being 14.13 MB

This is as expected. During training there is intermediate state information saved that the model needs during training but not for inference.